# Create ssh tunnel for avoid firewall blocking

Tags: ssh, port, firewall, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have remote host/server with ssh access.

I have my computer in my work network which can connect via ssh only
   in within this network.

And i can not connect via ssh to other world because of port 22
   blocked by firewall.

I am trying to create ssh tunnel to forward example localhost:80  to remote_server:22.(i suppose to connect via ssh to localhost and will be forwarded to my remote server)

I tried for example without proxy 
         `sudo ssh -L localhost:443:remote_server_ip:22 root@remote_host_name`
and with proxy 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tunneling_SSH_through_HTTP_proxies_using_HTTP_Connect

I have read a lot and checked stackoverflow but it still is not clear for me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Some ideas? I just want to avoid firewall blocking.